# What event can I use when setting TreeView.SelectedNode = null?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I set `SelectedNode` to `null` the tree updates correctly but `BeforeSelect` and `AfterSelect` do not fire.

Is there any way to tell when the selection has been changed to null?

My first thought is to extend the control and add an event though I would have thought something like this would already be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is good. However, I just discovered this control (keep an eye on SO's right column :)):

http://treeviewadv.sourceforge.net/

which supports what you're looking for, maybe has other goodies too...

Comment: Hi Sorin, I think that is possibly a very good solution and if I hadn't already implemented my solution yesterday I would have gone with it :) However, I'm marking your solution as answered for other users who might be looking for solving the same problem, though for those looking please understand I have not yet tested this control.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only way I could do this was to create a new control and provide a new implementation for `SelectedNode`, even `OnAfterSelect` and `OnBeforeSelect` weren't getting called.

```
public new TreeNode SelectedNode {
    get { return base.SelectedNode; }
    set {
        // Remember, if `value' is not null this will be called in `base'.
        if (value == null) {
            TreeViewCancelEventArgs args
                = new TreeViewCancelEventArgs(value, false, TreeViewAction.Unknown);
            OnBeforeSelect(args);
            if (args.Cancel)
                return;
        }
        base.SelectedNode = value;
        // Remember, if `value' is not null this will be called in `base'.
        if (value == null) {
            OnAfterSelect(new TreeViewEventArgs(value, TreeViewAction.Unknown));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good workaround to me but the question is why didn't MS implement it like this from the beginning? Overlooking something?

Comment: MS overlook a lot of things Sorin ;)